# jQuery to disable dropdown on checkbox click AND insert TRUE/FALSE value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I am using this code to disable a dropdown when user clicks on a checkbox

```
function onCheckChange() {
  if ($("#all_day_checkbox").is(':checked'))
    $("#evt_time_drop").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  else
    $("#evt_time_drop").removeAttr('disabled');
}

$("#all_day_checkbox").click(onCheckChange).change(onCheckChange);
```

This works fine. But I would like to add an instruction to inject a `true` or `false` value to the checkbox so this can be stored in the database.

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
function onCheckChange() {
  if ($("#all_day_checkbox").is(':checked'))
    $("#evt_time_drop").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#all_day_checkbox").val("TRUE");
  else
    $("#evt_time_drop").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#all_day_checkbox").val("FALSE");
}

$("#all_day_checkbox").click(onCheckChange).change(onCheckChange);
```

Anyone have suggestions to get to work?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
$("#all_day_checkbox").val("FALSE");//For initially make the `checkbox` value FALSE

function onCheckChange() {
    if ($("#all_day_checkbox").is(':checked')) {
        $("#evt_time_drop").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#all_day_checkbox").val("TRUE");
    } else {
        $("#evt_time_drop").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
$("#all_day_checkbox").click(onCheckChange).change(onCheckChange);
```

Comment: thanks @abdullah - this works nicely - still need to put `$("#all_day_checkbox").val("FALSE");` inside the `else` or this will work only for one click on the checkbox

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
$("#all_day_checkbox").attr("checked", "") //for removing the check
$("#all_day_checkbox").attr("checked","checked") //for checking the box
```

And then just checking to see if the "checked" value equals "checked"...

Comment: thanks @thomas - where should I insert your lines? i tried substituting lines 4 and 7 of my second code block in OP but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
function onCheckChange() {  
if ($("#all_day_checkbox").is(':checked')){
    $("#evt_time_drop").attr('disabled', 'disabled');    
    $("#all_day_checkbox").val("TRUE");   
}
else  
{  
    $("#evt_time_drop").removeAttr('disabled');  
    $("#all_day_checkbox").val("FALSE"); 
} 
}
```